# I am trying to convert ppt into pdf using Apache POI but getting following error.Please help me out of this

Tags: apache-poi, hslf

Following code is used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/hp/Downloads/sampPPT.ppt");

    HSLFSlideShow ppt = new HSLFSlideShow(is);
    is.close();
    Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
    int idx = 1;
    for (HSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        // clear the drawing area
        graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width, pgsize.height));
        // render
        slide.draw(graphics);
        // save the output
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/hp/Downloads/slide-" + idx + ".png");
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
        out.close();
        idx++;
    }

}
```

This throws following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl tried to access private field org.apache.poi.POIDocument.directory (org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl and org.apache.poi.POIDocument are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl.readCurrentUserStream(HSLFSlideShowImpl.java:340)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl.<init>(HSLFSlideShowImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl.<init>(HSLFSlideShowImpl.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl.<init>(HSLFSlideShowImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShow.<init>(HSLFSlideShow.java:138)
    at PPTConv.PPTConv.main(PPTConv.java:27)
```

Comment: This kind of exception occur if  you mix POI jars from different versions. This is not supported. See [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204). In your special case you probably have `poi-*.jar` and `poi-scratchpad-*.jar` from different versions in your classpath. I guess `poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar` together with `poi-3.16.jar` or later.

Comment: Thanks.It helped me, my problem is resolved now.

Comment: Could you please help me with HWPF conversion into pdf with exact format ? As I am doing but it is extracting text only.

Comment: This would be a new question. But as far as I know, there is not any good `HWPF` to `PDF` converter until now. There is [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport). But this only has `XWPF` converter. And even this is very incomplete until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an answer why such exceptions occur. Maybe it is helpful for others too:

This kind of exception occur if you mix `Apache POI` jars from different versions. This is not supported. See [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204).

In that special case there probably are `poi-*.jar` and `poi-scratchpad-*.jar` from different versions in classpath. The class `org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl`, which extends `org.apache.poi.POIDocument`, is contained in `poi-scratchpad-*.jar` while `org.apache.poi.POIDocument` is contained in  `poi-*.jar`. If those `*.jar`s are from different versions, then following can occur:

The `org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl` of `poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar` calls `currentUser = new CurrentUserAtom(directory);` in code line 340. This is possible because it extends `org.apache.poi.POIDocument` and this has field `protected DirectoryNode directory;` in version `3.15` (`poi-3.15.jar`).

But the same class `org.apache.poi.POIDocument` of version `3.16` (`poi-3.16.jar`) has field `private DirectoryNode directory;`.  So if `org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl` of version `3.15` calls `currentUser = new CurrentUserAtom(directory);` in code line 340, but `org.apache.poi.POIDocument` is from version `3.16`, then `java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShowImpl tried to access private field org.apache.poi.POIDocument.directory` is thrown because it really tries to access a private field now.